# Fat jar is missing with junit dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, fatjar

I am building a fat jar using maven-assembly-plugin. The jar is generated successfully. The only dependency I have for my project is: JUnit. But in the fat jar, I am unable to see this included (using jar tf command). Is JUnit dependency not included in fat jar usually  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

junit is usually a `test` scoped dependency, and then it will not be included.

Dependencies with scope `test` are meant to used during the build for tests, so there is no need to include them into the final JAR.

If, for some reason, you need junit in the final JAR, you need to change the scope to `compile`.

Comment: Actually one more question.. In the compile phase (and the goal as well), I don't mention what type of compiler (java/scala/C etc..) to use and as well as the version. But the phase/goal detects java compiler (along with version) and generates the class files. Could you please help me to understand how this happens behind the scenes.

Comment: The maven compile plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ is automatically attached to the compile phase. If you have any questions about that, please ask a new question here on SO.